# Can't echo variable

Tags: php

I'm thinking it's the smarty templates setup that is preventing me from echo'ing the $setlnk variable elsewhere on the page. Or, am i'm doing something else wrong. Is there another method I could use?

```
<?php
$setlnk = "<img src='/files/pvtexp.php?mid=" . $set[2] . "&iid=" . $set[3] . "&idat=" . $set[4] . "/" . $set[5] . "&sec=" . $set[6] . "'>";
```

echo $setlnk; // works
    ?>

```
..... html code

<?=$setlnk;?> // doesn't work
<?php echo $setlnk; ?> // doesn't work
```

Comment: do you have short open tags activated? how about echo?

Comment: check if short open tags are enabled, though you should get an error displayed if they aren't... and use <?php echo $setlnk;?> instead of <?=$setlnk;?>

Comment: Try to put the <?= $setlnk ?>
just after the first <?php $setlnk = [...]?> if it shows the code it means that something is changing that variable, if not.. it means that the short tags are not working in your server, so try <?php echo $setlnk;?>

Comment: have you checked your short open tags?

Comment: yes short take is enabled and i've also tried <?php echo method as well.

Comment: Maybe the output is hidden due malformed HTML? Check the source.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');                                          And check for error.

Comment: have you verified the variable array $set is ... erm set :) ?

Comment: Turned on error_reporting, and removed all html coding and still nothing. i guess it has something to do with how smarty template system parse the pages.

Comment: Brian, it works if I put echo $setlnk in the first php code set it works fine. it just doesn't work when I take it out of there

Comment: Remove all "..... html code" and test again.

Comment: I hope you're seeing results by checking HTML source, not watching regular browser's screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this is a smarty template, you need to do the following:

- **PHP file:** $template->assign('setlnk', $setlnk); // template is the SMARTY template object
- **TPL file (smarty template)**: {$setlnk}